# Why does dig take much longer than DNS query time?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I'm investigating slow DNS responses on Ubuntu, I have installed `bind9` to improve times from local cache, but still something is odd. What could make `dig` wait for 10 seconds and say that query time took 0?

```
time dig google.ro +all

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1.1 <<>> google.ro +all
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 9665
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.ro.                     IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 17 20:15:19 CET 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38

dig google.ro +all  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.012 total
```

Comment: The status is `SERVFAIL`, it looks like something is wrong with your DNS server (it doesn't return anything), and 10 seconds is just `dig`'s timeout.

Comment: @ChrisDown thanks for pointing this out. I would accept this as an answer. 0 msec is misleading.

Comment: Ubuntu has been shipping dnsmasq and uses it by default, which already gives you a caching name server. I don't think there is anything to be gained by adding another one.

Comment: @Rumca Sure thing, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status is `SERVFAIL`, it looks like something is wrong with your DNS server (it doesn't return anything), and 10 seconds is just `dig`'s timeout.